# I can't see or use common UI elements

Tags: unity

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 for a few days on my laptop and today Unity hang up. So I restarted my laptop. The situation now is, that I can see my wallpaper and the password-dialog to unlock the key ring. I also see the menu in the top left with "Datei" ("File" in English), "Bearbeiten" ("Edit"), and so on. There is nothing on the panel in the top right and no menu on the left hand side. If I wait until the screen gets black, I have to unlock the session and if I do so, there is the same situation again. Switching to the console and back is without success, too. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Bummer, sounds like unity/compiz has crashed on startup.  Can you edit your question with relevant output from `~/.xsession-errors` (if there is any in there)?

As a workaround you can switch to unity-2d from the gear menu on the login screen.